# Django CKeditor rendering weirdly only in one place

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using django-ckeditor-4.4.4, It's configured properly as far as I know and the widget works great in the admin panel and in an upload page I created. I know created an edit page for the same model and the ckeditor widget is rendering weridly and not responsive at all.

here it is rendered fine in the upload page I created:

it works fine and dandy

[image: Fine]

here it is in the edit page for the exact same Model:

It looks a bit different, the buttons don't work.
I'm seriously completely confused.
I don't know how to fix this, any help at all would be amazing

[image: Odd]

Comment: are any errors displayed to the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.. apparently ck-editor freaks if you accidentally apply any styling to a div that is wrapping it.

remove all styling, problem solved.